# How to style the progress bar number counter

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I want to know how can I be able to style the progress bar number counter. Basically I want to make the number bold and I have tested several ways but they didn't work.

Here's the link to jsfiddle:  **https://jsfiddle.net/7fu0mr3t**/

So how can I be able to access the counter numbers stylesheets in my css file and make some changes in order to display them in my own way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.progressbar li:before {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Numbers are added in the before, they are not in the html :-)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fu0mr3t/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can style them with two ways see fiddle

```
.progressbar li.active:before {
    color: blue;
    font-style: italic;
}
.progressbar li:before{
  color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7fu0mr3t/4/

Answer (score 0):

just add this **"font-weight: bold;"**

```
.progressbar li:before {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```